# Bluetooth peer connection reset

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi friends,
              I'm trying to send an file from android device to specific bluetooth device by using third party api called bluecove with obex. I can able to connect the device when connection header set I'm facing up an problem that **peer connection reset.**

Here my below code snippet. any help on this appreciated.

In my activity I'm using below code to process send file

```
BlueCoveImpl.setConfigObject(
                BlueCoveConfigProperties.PROPERTY_ANDROID_CONTEXT,
                this);
String deviceAddress = "0007ABB6D96E";
            int channel = 9;
            String obexURL = "btgoep://" + deviceAddress + ":"
                    + "0000110600001000800000805f9b34fb" + ";android=true";

            // String obexURL = "btgoep://" + deviceAddress + ":" + channel
            // + ";android=true";
            String fileToSend = "sdcard/DSCN9379.jpg";
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + obexURL);
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileToSend);
            File f = new File(fileToSend);
            int size = (int) f.length();
            byte file[] = new byte[size];
            stream.read(file);
            String filename = f.getName();
            System.out
                    .println("***************Now sending file to device*****************");
            SendFileTask task = new SendFileTask(MainActivity.this, obexURL,
                    file, filename);
            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();
```

================ below that i'm trying to connect bluecove connection class object with header set as follows.

```
package com.example.bluecovesample;

import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connection;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.obex.ClientSession;
import javax.obex.HeaderSet;
import javax.obex.Operation;
import javax.obex.ResponseCodes;

//import static write ;  
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendFileTask implements Runnable {

    private byte[] file;
    private String filename;
    public static final int WRITE = 2;

    String logString;

    int responseCode;
    Context context;
    String obexURL;

    public SendFileTask(Context ctx, String obexUrl, byte[] file,
            String filename) {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.obexURL = obexUrl;
        this.file = file;
        this.filename = filename;

    }

    public void run() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            System.out.println(obexURL);
            // for ( int i = 0; i 3; i++ )
            {
                // connection = Connector.open("btgoep://"+btConnectionURL+
                // ":6");
                connection = Connector.open(obexURL);
            }
            // connection obtained

            // now, let's create a session and a headerset objects
            ClientSession cs = (ClientSession) connection;

            HeaderSet hs = cs.createHeaderSet();
            // toastMsg(hs.toString());
            // now let's send the connect header
            // cs.notifyAll();

            **cs.connect(hs);**

            hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, filename);
            // System.out.println("sfname:"+filename);
            int dotIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
            // System.out.println("doti:"+dotIndex);
            String extension = filename.substring(dotIndex).toLowerCase();
            // System.out.println("sfname:"+extension);

            if (extension.equals(".txt")) {
                hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "text/plain");
            } else if (extension.equals(".jpg") || extension.equals(".jpeg")) {
                hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            } else if (extension.equals(".mpeg") || extension.equals(".mpg")
                    || extension.equals(".mp3")) {
                hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "video/mpeg");
            } else if (extension.equals(".wav")) {
                hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "audio/x-wav");
            } else if (extension.equals(".3gp")) {
                hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            } else if (extension.equals("mid") || extension.equals("rmi")) {
                hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "audio/mid");
            }

            hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.LENGTH, new Long(file.length));

            Operation putOperation = cs.put(hs);

            // System.out.println("response code:"+putOperation.getResponseCode());

            // putOperation.getResponseCode();
            // this.responseCode = putOperation.getResponseCode();

            OutputStream outputStream = putOperation.openOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(file);
            // file push complete

            outputStream.close();
            responseCode = putOperation.getResponseCode();

            putOperation.close();

            cs.disconnect(null);

            connection.close();

            // file successfully sent

            System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE " + responseCode);
            if (responseCode == ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println("FILE SUCCESSFULLY SENT " + filename);
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("FILE SUCCESSFULLY NOT SENT" + filename
                        + " not in exception");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("FILE SUCCESSFULLY NOT SENT" + filename
                    + " in exception");
            // System.out.println("In exception");
            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("error closing connection" + ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void toastMsg(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

While executing the above code i got connection accept notification dialog on destination device and then notified that peer connection  rest at while executing line *cs.connect(hs); in my logcat. 
Logcat stack trace :

> 07-11 14:48:07.044: W/System.err(4527): java.io.IOException:
>   Connection reset by peer 07-11 14:48:07.052: W/System.err(4527):  at
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readNative(Native Method) 07-11
>   14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):     at
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:336) 07-11
>   14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):     at
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
>   07-11 14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):   at
>   com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackAndroid.connectionRfRead(BluetoothStackAndroid.java:437)
>   07-11 14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):   at
>   com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothRFCommInputStream.read(BluetoothRFCommInputStream.java:139)
>   07-11 14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):   at
>   com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXUtils.readFully(OBEXUtils.java:71) 07-11
>   14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):     at
>   com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXSessionBase.readPacket(OBEXSessionBase.java:217)
>   07-11 14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):   at
>   com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXClientSessionImpl.connectImpl(OBEXClientSessionImpl.java:100)
>   07-11 14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):   at
>   com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXClientSessionImpl.connect(OBEXClientSessionImpl.java:85)
>   07-11 14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):   at
>   com.example.bluecovesample.SendFileTask.run(SendFileTask.java:78)
>   07-11 14:48:07.059: W/System.err(4527):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the client is cutting the connection. This could be due to several reasons such as sending wrong data or wrong pairing. Did you make sure you are pairing devices correctly?

Pairing code not being entered could be a issue. This makes the pairing improper.

The fix is to enter Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Bluetooth settings, long press on the "paired" device and select 'Unpair', then single press on the device which produced a 'Bluetooth pairing request' window with textfield, into which I typed the PIN (pairing code). After this was done, pairing will be successful.

You can also use a program called Wireshark to analyze the messages send through the protocol.

Comment: ...i can able to connect but when I reach cs.connect(hs); trying to set headerset for connected device to send file, it gets disconnected.any other solutin for this.

Comment: Do you have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and BLUETOOTH permissions in your manifest?

Comment: If yes, have a look at the source codes here: http://gitorious.org/android-obex and compare your code.

Comment: ..I really tried to extract the code from the link you provided..but i don't understood the gitorios set up in my system.while checkout it asks some Hash key..how and where should i generate this hash.

Comment: .thanks for your replies. Can you please provide me an step by step command to execute above fuse file to make it use on android app with my windows dev environment.I also gone through this readme file and install file but i doesn't get how to make it use with command tool.

Comment: I did my best to help you with my limited knowledge about it and the rest is up to you. Please start a new question about that or search the internet for it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.obex.ClientSession;
```

you use this class "ClientSession".

as far as I know, createHeaderSet is not a method of ClientSession

I wonder how you compile your app successfully.